# Angular2 share data between 2 instances of same service

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular-services, data-sharing

Is it possible to share the data between 2 instances of the same service?

**DateService.ts**

```
private _selectedDate: Date = new Date();

private _mode = 'YEAR'; //can be DAY,WEEK,MONTH also

set selectedDate(newSelectedDate) {
        this._selectedDate = newSelectedDate;
    }

    get selectedDate() {
        return this._selectedDate;
    }

set mode(newMode) {
        this._mode = newMode;
    }

    get mode() {
        return this._mode;
    }

nextDate() {
      //based on mode this will change the date
     // if the mode is year then this gives next year
     // if the mode is month then next month etc... and updates the date  
    }
```

Same date I need to use on multiple pages in my application. But mode I want to make it specific to component which uses this service.

```
<some-component [(date)]="dateService.selectedDate" [(mode)]="YEAR"></some-component>
```

when I click nextDate button from this component it should go to next year

```
<someother-component [(date)]="dateService.selectedDate" [(mode)]="DAY"></someother-component>
```

when I click nextDate from this component it should go to next day

Comment: You can use a different service and inject this service to both service instances to share data.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you please let me know how to inject one service inside another. I tried this constructor(@Inject(DateService) dateService) {
        
    }
but it's not working

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I got it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the mode as a parameter.

**In `Component1`:**

```
private mode = 'YEAR';

nextDate = this.dateService.nextDate(this.mode);
```

**In `Component2`:**

```
private mode = 'DAY';

nextDate = this.dateService.nextDate(this.mode);
```

**In `DateService`:**

```
nextDate(mode) {
     // do stuff with the mode. mode will be different depending who calls this function. 
     // If Component1 calls, mode will be YEAR. If Component2 calls, mode will be DAY.
}
```

Basically, whenever you call `nextDate()` from your common `DateService` make sure you are passing the mode as a parameter and you are set.